# Handling a List <Integer> to a thread

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Basically I have an integer array which i want to hand over to a thread, but i can't get the syntax right.

```
// Create list
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Create thread
TPServer server = new TPServer(port, <Integer> list);  
new Thread(server).start();



// Below is the TPServer class
// TPServer Class
public class TPServer implements Runnable {

private List <Integer> list = null;
private int port = 0;
private boolean isStopped = false;

public TPServer(int port, List <Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.port = port;
}
}
```

Comment: `new TPServer(port, list);` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented `Runnable` and also it should be `new TPServer(port, list);`

Comment: Thanks Petar, I thought it would work. Restarted Netbeans and the errors cleared away. :P

Answer (score 1):

You pass a generic argument the same as any other.

```
TPServer server = new TPServer(port, list);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter Lawrey. I think it's Netbeans. After restarting, the errors cleared away.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use a list that uses a semaphore to prevent concurent access Or use a list type that is thread safe, if your list is being used also out of the thread. (and if it is used only inside the thread, create it inside obviously :=) )

Comment: Hi Vincent Piel, Thanks. The list is created for reading only so I wont be implementing concurrent access for this application I'm writing. Thanks!